# wsimport ant task failing (package name is invalid)

Tags: ant, jaxb, jax-ws, webservice-client, wsimport

I am trying to generate client files using wsdl and xsd. During wsimport ant task, i am getting an error saying package name is invalid. After inspecting, i came to know that namespace contained a keyword Public which is causing the issue.

When i changed it to _public, the build was successful. I checked the documentation for any options to make this conversion on the fly during wsimport task itself but not able to find any solution.

Is there a way to add underscore(_) automatically before public during wsimport ant task?